# Easy way to determine matrix positive / negative definiteness

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, positive-definite, hessian-matrix

So I have this math final coming up on Wednesday, and recently we have been finding critical points for two variable function using the Hessian matrix, and we didn't really explicitly learn how to find out the definiteness of the Hessian matrix in order to determine whether the point is a min/max etc.

I was wondering if there is a good way to be able to find this out, something quick and simple that I could apply in the exam.

So far in the couple of example we had, the prof. said that if the value of the top left element of the matrix is greater than 0, as well as the determinant, then it's positive semi-definite. But I think this only works for positive matrices.

We're more than likely only going to be dealing with real numbers, rather than complex numbers, so I'm looking for something applicable for real matrices.

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

This is the criterion you are referring to. As far as I know this is the quickest one you can apply in full generality. Otherwise you should compute the spectrum of the matrix, and this is much lengthier.

Comment: Yes, however, if I understood correctly, that only applies for positive semi-definiteness, but nor for the negative? I mean if the top left element was negative, and the determinant was also negative, that doesn't mean that the matrix is negative semi-definite... Right?

Comment: You are right that the Wikipedia page is not well written. The criterion for negative definiteness is the following: a symmetric matrix is negative definite if and only if the first leading minor is negative, the second is positive, the third is negative and so on. To remember those criteria, apply them to a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 6):

I know these two criteria: A symmetric matrix is positive definite iff all eigenvalues are greater zero, positive semidefinite iff alle eigenvalues are greater or equal zero, and analogous for negative eigenvalues. It is indefinite, if there are positive and negative eigenvalues.

Then, there's Sylversters Criterion, which says that a symmetric matrix is positive definite iff the leading principial minors have positive determinant, which is in your case the top-left element and the 2x2-determinant. For positive semi-definiteness, you have to consider all principal minors. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion.

Example:
Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$. Since $\det(1) = 1 > 0$ and $\det(A) = -7$, the matrix is not positive definite. But the characteristic polynomial is $\chi(x) = x^2 + 2x - 7$ and has a positive and a negative root, thus $A$ has a positive and a negative eigenvalue, so it is indefinite.

Comment: So, safest way is to simply find the eigenvalues? We have been dealing a lot with Eigenvalues in recent times...

Comment: I would assume so. Especially for 2x2-matrices, calculating the eigenvalues is really simple since the characteristic polynomial is always of degree 2, so most time you can directly see what the sign of the eigenvalues is. And with "positive" I mean $> 0$, so don't mix that up. :)

Comment: Yeah I guess that must be the easiest and safest way to approach this. Since we're only dealing with 2 variable function, the Hessian Matrix is gonna be a 2x2. And yeah it'll be easy to calculate the eigenvalues quickly and figure out the definiteness.

Comment: If any eigenvalue is $0$, then so is the determinant, so you know in that case that the matrix is not going to be positive-definite. There’s no need to check all of the minors of a $2\times2$ matrix if you want to know whether or not such a matrix is positive-indefinite, though, since the trace of the matrix gives you the other eigenvalue.